# removing gridview records via button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, gridview, edit

i'm trying to remove a specific gridview record from the grid by using a certain button with a function, I seem to be getting a "NullReferenceException was unhandled error" everytime i select a record to be removed. (records are in a "Edit" state.

[image: Form Design]
[image: Actual Error]

These buttons work fine when i add a new set of gridview records, I may add and remove them as i wish, the errors started popping up when I edit the records.

**Code for Remove Button:**

```
 int nCurrentRow = -1;
        nCurrentRow = Convert.ToInt16(grdWorkers.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString());
        if (nCurrentRow != -1)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dsDetail1.Tables["Workers2"].Rows[nCurrentRow];
            dsDetail1.Tables["Workers2"].Rows.Remove(dr);
        }


        grdWorkers.DataSource = null;
        grdWorkers.DataSource = dsDetail1.Tables["Workers2"];
        grdWorkers.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: change this to `nCurrentRow = grdWorkers.CurrentCell.RowIndex;` row index already returns int. Did you fill the gridview again when you click the edit state? it had to be refresh so data is updated immediately

Comment: I guess `dsDetail1.Tables` is giving error. Am I right?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but it looks like you are getting the index from the DataGrid or DatagridView (I am not sure which you used. I am using a DataGridView). Your code:

```
nCurrentRow = Convert.ToInt16(grdWorkers.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString());
```

This will return the index of the selected cell in the DataGridView. Then below that you use that index on the DataTable.

```
DataRow dr;
dr = dsDetail1.Tables["Workers2"].Rows[nCurrentRow];
dsDetail1.Tables["Workers2"].Rows.Remove(dr);
```

If your DataGridView has a DataSource which it appears it does, then the two indexes will not necessarily be the same. Below is what I use to get the index to the DataTable of the selected item in the DataGridView.

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
DataRow dr = drv.Row;
int indexToTable = dgvDataTable.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
```

Hope this helps.